# Android Google Map and firebase Dependency Issue

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, kotlin, dependencies

I am working on maps along with firebase for the very first time and stuck on dependency issue.

```
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1.
```

However following rest of questions on SO(in order to avoid version conflicts) that update

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

to

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.1'

doesn't work for me.
Similarly, updating

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
>   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

to

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.0'
>   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.0'

doesn't work either. Both cases given the same error that dependency doesn't exists. 
Other than these I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding project but that doesn't work too. Please help me with this issue

**BUILD.GRADLE(app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.watersystem.client"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**BUILD.GRADLE(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please add the entire content of your build.gradle file.

Comment: Please see the updated question. Thank you

Comment: Try replacing `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` with
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Comment: Not working. Given same error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few more combinations of dependencies, converting below 3 lines

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
```

worked for me.